# How to implement parse json using url in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this url : http://shops.alpha-trend.com/mobileapp/productinfo.php?productId=4363&function=GetProductInfo&show=yes. when i test this url in browser it contains json array in which product ,image and description and many other attributes are present. How i this parse this json in java to display product,image and description.Pleas help me through proper code.Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several examples of doing this available, a quick search turned up two that look good:

[JSON Android ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318761/json-android-listview)

This answer looks pretty much complete but is missing the HttpClient step, which you can find an example implementation in the next answer:

http://mobile.dzone.com/news/android-tutorial-how-parse

Comment: [{"0":"4363","record_id":"4363","1":"54621681","shop_id":"54621681","2":"25","category_id":"25","3":"","category1":"","4":"Dress 10012","product":"Dress 10012","5":"5000","price":"5000","6":"My Description\r\nMy Description\r\nMy Description\r\nMy Description","desc":"My Description\r\nMy Description\r\nMy Description\r\nMy Description","7":"http:\/\/www.shoppingmall.pk\/images\/menuimages\/54621681\/4363","products_image":"http:\/\/www.shoppingmall.pk\/images\/menuimages\/54621681\/4363","8":"1","status":"1","9":null,"external_link":null}], In this json data i don;t know which is main node?

Comment: The above json data is present in this url:http://shops.alpha-trend.com/mobileapp/productinfo.php?productId=4363&function=GetProductInfo&show=yes

Comment: the url u r given me contain node like earthquake ,please tell me in my json data ,which node i consider main node